# RAM Allocation for Ubuntu running in VM on windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, ssd, windows-10, ram

I want to use Ubuntu on an Oracle VM on Windows 10. However, I am stuck on the RAM allocation screen when setting up Ubuntu on the VM. My computer has a core i5 processor, 8gb ram, 500gb ssd and 2.30GHz frequency. It is fairly new and never hangs on Windows when running several heavy applications. How much RAM should I allocate the Ubuntu installation for it to remain as fast both on windows and on ubuntu? How will the ram allocated impact the speed of windows 10?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer this question accurately would require me to write a book about how modern operating systems use memory and how the word “memory” does not equate to RAM. Instead, I will ask: Why are you making a VM of Ubuntu? If it’s a tiny Ubuntu Server installation for web development, you might get away with a 768MB or 1.5GB allocation. If you want the full shebang, then maybe a dual-boot is better. There is insufficient information in the question to answer this beyond speculation and conjecture 

Comment: " How much RAM should I allocate the Ubuntu installation for it to remain as fast both on windows and on ubuntu? "  You really need to test this yourself and see what you feel is the correct amount.

Comment: This veers REALLY close to being opinion based.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improve performance of Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox on Windows 10 host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954128/improve-performance-of-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox-on-windows-10-host)