# How to change config of existing unmutable VM(or clone it)?

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I have created a ubuntu VM using Virtualbox on a windows host machine. I realised that I have assigned it more number of CPUs than my host has, and hence performance is pretty bad. So I tried to change its config:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm myubuntuvm --cpus 3
```

But this couldn't work as I have my VM in saved state.

```
vboxmanage.exe: error: the machine is not mutable (state is saved)
```

On further internet search, I came to know that I can clone existing VM.
But when I try to do it via virtualbox UI, I don't see any option to change the config.

What is the correct way to get it done? Either on original VM or a new one cloned from original.

Comment: The allocations to the VM are done within the HOST OS & your virtualization software...  The VM OS (Ubuntu 20.04) isn't involved (*just as its not involved in the cloning of the VM itself; that is done on the HOST OS*)

Comment: @guiverc, so what should be the way to go ahead? VM is pretty slow. I see the message something like, 'Invalid configuration. VM has more CPUs than system has. It may impact the performance'.

Comment: I'm not an expert in managing VMs within `virtualbox`, but I'd make changes to `virtualbox` within in your HOST OS where the VM itself is controlled; that is within windows as I read your question with Ubuntu being only the VM you want to configure. You're asking in the wrong place was my point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improve performance of Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox on Windows 10 host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954128/improve-performance-of-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox-on-windows-10-host)